# Can't get all the data of one column using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using beautifulSoup to extract some data off of a wiki, but I can only get the first data of a specific column. If my understanding of for-loops is correct, it should loop through everything in the table. I tested this by printing "t" to the console and it shows all the data in HTML format. Is there a reason why this is happening?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, csv
import pandas as pd

wiki_url = "https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Mandarin_Frequency_lists/1-1000"
table_id = "wikitable"

response = requests.get(wiki_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

#table = soup.find('table', class_="wikitable")
table = soup.find_all('table', class_="wikitable")

with open('chinesewords.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as c:
    writer = csv.writer(c)
    writer.writerow(["simplified, pinyin"])

    for t in table:
        simplified = t.find('span', class_="Hans").text
        print(simplified)
```

The output:

```
一
```

(I apologize in advance if I didn't follow the rules of StackOverflow posting, as this is my first time posting a question)

Comment: You have to iterate over every element within the table, thus you have to extract every `td` or `tr` (depending on which info you want to have). Like: `table.findAll("td")` and then extract the text via `.text` or the text from the `<span>`, as you did.

Answer (score 0):

Make your life easier and try `pandas.read_html()`.

Here's an example:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

table = (
    pd
    .read_html(
        requests
        .get(
            "https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Mandarin_Frequency_lists/1-1000"
        ).text,
        flavor="lxml"
    )[0]
)
table.to_csv("mandarin_frequency_lists.csv", index=False)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you mean data from one column from the table, the following code is enough. I hope I helped:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, csv
import pandas as pd

wiki_url = "https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Mandarin_Frequency_lists/1-1000"

response = requests.get(wiki_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

table_column = soup.find_all('span', class_="Hans")

with open('chinesewords.csv', 'w', encoding='utf32', newline='') as c:
    writer = csv.writer(c)
    writer.writerow(["simplified, pinyin"])
    for t in table_column:
        simplified = t.text
        print(simplified)
        writer.writerow(simplified)
```